# Add a separator in md-autocomplete list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, md-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete list which is composed of two varieties of inputs - Airports and Resorts. I want to add separator text delineating each set of Autocomplete options. Like this
[Delienated options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfaQz.png)

However, all I have been able to manage to do is add the 'Separator' labels as items to the options list. Like This:
['Separator' labels added as items to the options list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3gSG.png)

The problem is

1. There is no way I can prevent users from selecting the Separator
   fields as actual inputs
2. The solution looks very ugly

Is there any other way to create 'Separator Labels' in md-autocomplete? Or any way to at least solve the above two problems highlighted?

Answer (score 1):

md-autocomplete hasn't this feature.
But you can emulate autocomplete with md-select

`<md-select ng-model="destination" multiple>
    <md-optgroup label="Airpot">
        <md-option ng-value="destination.name" ng-repeat="airport in destinations | filter: {category: 'airport' }">{{airport.name}}</md-option>
    </md-optgroup>
</md-select>`

`<md-optgroup>` is the thing which allow to create not selectable item (headers of categories)